# Building Opencv using cmake giving errors involving c++11

Tags: python, opencv, c++11, ubuntu, cmake

I am facing problem with the cmake command while compiling opencv on Ubuntu 16.04. When I execute the cmake command, I get the error

*CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (message):
FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed.
You should create a separate directory for build files.*

I have extracted the opencv source file in a folder named opencv-3.3.1
Then I have followed all the processes mentioned in this site

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

I use the following commands ::

`cd opencv-3.3.1/
mkdir build/
cd build/
cmake -D CMA
KE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..`

But I am getting this error!

What can be the possible problem?

The CMakeError.log shows

**error "C++11 is not supported**

I have tried adding `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")` to the beginning of the CMakeLists.txt and also included the flag `-DENABLE_CXX11=ON` to the `CMAKE` command flags. But nothing seems to work.

Please help!!

Comment: What cmake generator is being used? Probably g++, but what version?

Comment: gcc version 5.4.0

Answer (score 3):

Maybe there is a file called `CMakeCache.txt` in your OpenCV root directory  `opencv-3.3.1`.

Just remove it!

That's because someone have executed `cmake .` inside the root directory `opencv-3.3.1` before.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
```

to your cmakelists file.

Comment: Instead of thie line :: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11")` ??

Comment: Now it shows this error :: `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (message):
  

  FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed.

         You should create a separate directory for build files.
`

Comment: I am calling the `cmake` command from within a `build` folder. And the `CMakeLists.txt` file is outside the `build` folder. But still this error.

Comment: Well, at least we've cleared up your first error. Now let's figure out where the rest is going wrong. First, you should delete all of the files in your build folder in order to start clean. Then `cd` into your now empty `build` folder and do `sudo cmake ..`. If that fails then we can work from there, if it succeeds you should add one directive at a time until you find the problem.